# How to export PowerShell's CTRL+R file?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been running the same Windows setup for too long. 
It has become slow and I believe putting a new setup from scratch would help.

The one thing that stops me from doing that is PowerShell's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> history, which I use extensively.

How do I export, and then import this history file after re-installing Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PSReadline stores the console history in this file:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

Copying that file across installations will bring over the history. The directory structure might not exist in the new installation at first, so after reinstalling, you should open a PowerShell prompt, run any command (thereby making PSReadline create the structure), close the prompt, and then paste the file.